# The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined

Tags: ansible

I am getting below error when I run the following playbook.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/thor/user.yml': line 8, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n      - name: create users\n        ^ here\n"}


---
- name: create user
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
      - name: create users
        user:
           name: "{{ item.name }}"
           state: present
      - debug:
           var: "{{ item.message }}"
        with_items:
              - { name: amit, message: amit_done }
              - { name: ankit, message: ankit_done }
```

This works when I comment debug module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to *`loop`* more than one task. Put the message into the *`label`* if you want to. For example

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: create users
      user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: present
      loop:
        - {name: amit, message: amit_done}
        - {name: ankit, message: ankit_done}
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.message }}"
```

---

Or, if you really need more tasks in the *`loop`*, it's possible to *`include_tasks`* in a *`loop`*. For example, create a file with all tasks

```yaml
shell> cat create_users.yml
- name: create users
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} done"
```

and include it in the *`loop`*

```yaml
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: create_users.yml
      loop:
        - amit
        - ankit
```